# Oracle SQL: Subtract multiple SQL statements from one SQL statement

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Hi stackoverflow community

I have the following problem and I'm in great hope someone can guide me in the right direction
Im using oracle database 11.2.0.4

```
select count(*)
from pi_track
```

==> returns 1'200'000 rows

And,

```
select count(*)
from pi_track
where  REGEXP_LIKE (track,'^[[:digit:]]{4}$')
```

==> returns 200'000 rows

How can I combine this two statements, such that the second statement is going to be subtracted from the first one and hence returns 1'000'000 rows?
What I am trying to do is to subtract from the first query several multiple ones, such that I have a result list where none of the where conditions (of regexp_like) apply (which then I can inspect manually)

Comment: Can you not just negate the WHERE clauses to get the correct count?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Negating it _might_ be costlier than a qualifying similar regex pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can negate `REGEXP_LIKE` with `NOT` and use several of them with `AND`.

Example:

```
WITH pi_track AS
 (SELECT 'aaaaa' AS track FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbbbb' AS track FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ccccc' AS track FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ddddd' AS track FROM dual)
SELECT count(*) FROM pi_track
  WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (track,'^a*$')
    AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (track,'^b*$');
```

Comment: `WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (track,'^[^(a|b)]*$');` - A better one.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your valuable inputs! Will play around with all of it

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually looking for the count:

```
with pt as (
  select
    count(*) c
  from pi_track
)
select
  pt.c - count(*)
from
  pt,
  pi_track
where
  REGEXP_LIKE (track,'^[[:digit:]]{4}$')
group by
  pt.c;
```

If you are actually wanting the data, and not just a count, you can actually subtract them using minus.

```
select * from pi_track
minus
select * from pi_track where REGEXP_LIKE (track,'^[[:digit:]]{4}$')
```

I haven't tested the performance, but it gives you another option.

Or you can just add NOT to your current select.

```
select count(*)
from pi_track
where not REGEXP_LIKE (track,'^[[:digit:]]{4}$')
```